# Why am I getting a 403 Forbidden when scraping with python?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, python-requests, request

I am trying to scrape a certain website let's call it "https://some-website.com".
For the past few months I was able to do it without problems however a few days ago I noticed the scraper no longer works as all requests return a 403 Forbidden status.

For the last 3 months I was using the below code to scrape the data.

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

res = requests.get(<url>, headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().random})
```

This always returned a nice 200 OK with the page I needed.
Until a few days ago I started getting a 403 Forbidden error. And somewhere in the return text I can spot a sentence **"Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue"**.

#### User-Agent issue

As you can see in the code I already randomly switch user-agent header which is usually the recommendation to fix this kind of problems.

#### IP issue

Naturally I suspected they blacklisted my IP (maybe in combination with some user agents and don't allow me to scrape). However I implemented a solution to use a proxy and I still get a 403.

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

proxies = {
   "https": f'http://some_legit_proxy',
   "http": f'http://some_legit_proxy',
}

res = requests.get(<url>, headers={'User-Agent': UserAgent().random}, proxies=proxies)
```

The proxy is a residential proxy.

#### Basic Attempt actually works

What baffles me the most is that if I remove the random user-agent part and use the default requests user-agent the scrape all of a sudden works.

```
import requests

res = requests.get(<url>) # 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.28.1'
# 200 OK
```

This tells me that it doesn't mean the website all of a sudden need javascript as the scrape does work it just seems they are somehow blocking me.

I have a few ideas in mind to work around this but as I don't understand how is this happening I cannot be sure this will be scalable in the future.

**Please help me understand what is happening here.**

Comment: There's a lot of possible reasons. They might be using a WAF provider like Cloudflare to block any requests coming from bots. They might be having a Javascript that needs to solve a challenge before you get access to the webpage.  But looking at how using the default user agent works, It's probably TLS fingerprinting.

Comment: Looks like they caught on to your actions. Sites generally don't appreciate you scraping their content.

Comment: @SalmanFarsi. Thanks for the quick response. I haven't heard of TLS fingerprinting. Is there any go-to action which can be taken to bypass it?

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably need rotating proxies or something that hides/bypasses device fingerprinting that might be exposing your script as a bot.

**Reference:**

[How Web Unlocker is enabling better fingerprinting, auto-unlocking, and CAPTCHA-solving](https://get.brightdata.com/bd-web-unlocker-enables-better-fingerprinting-auto-unlocking-and-captcha-solving)

Answer (score 1):

The site in question is hosted by Cloudflare. Cloudflare does things like TLS fingerprinting on the edge which will determine the User-Agent you've provided doesn't match the TLS fingerprint from Python's request module. This is a common technique used by cloud providers as a means for bot deterrence. I'd recommend first trying to scrape without spoofing the user agent and if you still have troubles consider a modern browser automation platform such as Puppeteer.

Good luck friend. :)

Comment: Do you know the python wrapper of puppeteer is any good? https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/

Comment: @DominikSajovic I haven't used it. It seems very similar to the NodeJS version though. If you're more comfortable with Python, and you are familiar with async programming, go for it!

Answer (score 0):

as @h0r53 mentioned, I think cloudfare detects if a request is made by js.

You could try using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75275395/20443541)